# How to execute UI Automator integration tests when building an Android app

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew, android-uiautomator

I have integrated UI Automator on my app, and in Android Studio I can execute the ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt and the test inside of it are executed.

I would know how can I execute these tests when I build the app with gradlew and not only when I run the test class.

I've tried these solutions:

- gradlew
- gradlew test
- gradlew assembleDebug

But I'm noticing these tests are not executed.

Also I would ask if it's possible that, if some tests are not passed, the build fails or I can't merge the branch the tests are executed into the master repository.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Espresso
[Test the UI of a single app](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing)

```
    dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}

@Test
    fun changeText_sameActivity() {
        // Type text and then press the button.
        onView(withId(R.id.editTextUserInput))
                .perform(typeText(stringToBetyped), closeSoftKeyboard())
        onView(withId(R.id.changeTextBt)).perform(click())

        // Check that the text was changed.
        onView(withId(R.id.textToBeChanged))
                .check(matches(withText(stringToBetyped)))
    }
```

Espresso code example
[Espresso code example](https://github.com/android/testing-samples)

Comment: Sorry but we're talking about different things, I'm talking about UI Automator and you're talking about Espresso, which have also different uses. I would know how to execute UI Automator tests during the build process